# How to change color of dropdownlist box where arrow is in IE?

Tags: css

How can i change background color of this gray box in IE? [image]

I have this css:

```
 .select-wrapper:after {
        content: "";
        background: rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) url('/Content/img/imgsprite.png') no-repeat;


        background-position: -144px -78px;
        width: 12px;
        height: 6px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        right: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) will help you further

Comment: @Xyv do u know maybe how can i implement that in my css?

Comment: We could take that to [chat] but I'm very limited in my time currently.

Comment: i just want to ask u do u know how to change box in IE of dropdown list...because now its gray i need to make it black ?

Comment: Can you give me a global link to the sprite image? I'll post an answer below

Comment: sprite is on local machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85000/discussion-between-none-and-xyv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this css along with background image,

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Good to know you find your answer. Thanks too.